# Difference Between Sending Mail Using Web.Helpers.WebMail and Net.Mail.SmtpClient

Tags: asp.net, .net, email, smtpclient

1. Is there any difference (pros/cons?) between sending e-mails using `System.Web.Helpers.WebMail` and using `System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient`?
2. As I know, `System.Web.Mail` namespace is considered obsolete. Does it apply to `WebMail` class?
3. Which one is better (if there is a differece) for ASP.NET web app or for Web API?

The way I see it now, `WebMail` provides me with an abstraction that I can use to send e-mails easily if I don't need to change configuration (host, credentials, etc.). I can configure it once on start and use from there. In case of `SmtpClient` I need to provide this abstraction myself.

Answer (score 0):

System.Web.Mail is not a .NET SMTP implementation. It uses CDONTS components. System.Net.Mail is a better choice since it is a fully managed .NET SMTP implementation.

Comment: You are correct. However, System.Web.Helpers.WebMail is not in System.Web.Mail namespace as I understand.

Comment: System.Web.Helpers.WebMail internally uses System.Net.Mail.